# Strange behavior with SliceDensityPlot3D using custom surfaces, Mesh lines have a great influence on the density plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107415/9490) I was trying to make a 3D stack of disk-shaped density plots, so I was using [`ListSliceDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListSliceDensityPlot3D.html).  I resorted to using a set of nonrectangular grid points that were drawn from a unit circle, and the corresponding `DensityPlot` was circular.  Something like this,

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[
 Flatten[
  Table[
   {#1, #2, z, Sin[(#1 - #2) z]} & @@@ RandomPoint[Disk[], 1000],
   {z, 1, 11, 2}],
  1],
 {"ZStackedPlanes", Range[1, 11, 2]}
 ]
```

[image]

But this seems a bit klunky, and only results in nice disk-shaped slices as the number of random points gets larger.

What I'd like to do is take advantage of the ability to specify your own surfaces as the second argument to `SliceDensityPlot3D` or its list variant, rather than using "ZStackedPlanes".

I know that any 3D region can be used as a surface, so I want to create a disk-shaped surface.  There isn't a built-in `Disk3D` function, but Taiki made such a function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79793/9490).

`disk3D[]` creates a [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html) out of a set of

```
{ListPointPlot3D @@ #, Graphics3D@#} &@disk3D[]
```

[image]

Here are the results when I try to use these `Polygon` objects as surfaceregions, compared to the built-in stacked planes:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
   Sin[(x - y) z], #, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 12}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50] & /@ {disk3D[{0, 0, #}] & /@ 
   Range[1, 11, 2], {"ZStackedPlanes", Range[1, 11, 2]}}
```

[image]

We see a clear distortion of the function, and the resulting plot has little to no connection with the underlying density.  I also receive repeated `RegionIntersection::reg` and `RegionBounds::reg` warnings.  I can make these warnings go away by discretizing the regions before feeding them to `SliceDensityPlot3D`, but that only brings the problem into sharper relief:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[Sin[(x - y) z], 
 DiscretizeGraphics[disk3D[{0, 0, #}]] & /@ Range[1, 11, 2], {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

The density plots seem to be sampled preferentially along the mesh lines created when discretizing the graphics:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[disk3D[{0, 0, 0}]]
```

[image]

This seems to clearly be a bug in `SliceDensityPlot3D` - one that is just as bad in `SliceContourPlot3D`.  Increasing the number of `PlotPoints` does not have an effect.

How can I turn the `disk3D` object into a surface in a better way?  Is there any way to ensure that the discretized graphics has a better mesh function?

For the record, it **is** possible to get the plot by the circuitous route of first creating a `ListContourPlot3D` object for each disk, discretizing that to create a surface region (again using `Quiet` because of the errors) - [thanks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105653/9490) to Szabolcs.  Using this [code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasondbiggs/9e239237f968104dc857/raw/d7d2f0768087fae8dcaad9c42a4802ed2fc53def/gistfile1.txt) (omitted here for brevity), we can see that it is necessary to get a very fine mesh to get a decent plot:

[image]

But that code is **very** slow, and I'd like to be able to use the `Polygon` objects instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can significantly speed things up by using `DiscretizeRegion` on `ImplicitRegion`.

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 Sin[(x - y) z], 
 {DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && z == #, {x, y, z}] & /@ 
    Range[1, 11, 2]},
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

It will work without `DiscretizeRegion` but does not produce as fine density slices and also requires `Quiet` in that case.

Hope this helps.

---

Actually you can stack any family of 2D regions with this method. For example:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 Sin[(x - y) z], {DiscretizeRegion@
     ImplicitRegion[
       #/100 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && 
         Abs[x] > #/100 && 
         z == #, 
      {x, y, z}] & /@ Range[1, 11, 2]}, 
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool - so the answer is to, if possible, discretize a regionwith `DiscretizeRegion`  rather than a graphics via `DiscretizeGraphics`

Comment: @JasonB That seems to be the case. It also works on 3D regions without `DiscretizeRegion`. However, the faces are not as fine.